# Java. How to get a list of exactly my servers in the local network?

Tags: java, networking, tcp

Using tcp sockets, I wrote a server, launched it on a computer. Wrote a client for android. Being in the same local network, I successfully connect from my smartphone knowing the local ip address of the computer and the server port.

The problem is that I want to run this server on multiple computers on the local network, and their local addresses can change.

Need to somehow scan and select an available server in the application.

How is it implemented? What is the special protocol for scanning? Or just try to connect by sorting through all possible addresses and ports?

Is UDP broadcast a bad solution?

Sorry for google-translator!

UPD: I am trying to make a remote PC application. This will not work on the global internet. only local network. Thanks for the answer

Comment: "_The problem is that I want to run this server on multiple computers on the local network, and their local addresses can change._" - This could also happen in your local server. That's why DNS was created. And if you are going to rely on IP addresses, they should be static and configured the same in your LANs.

Comment: By the sound of it, looks like you might be trying to [load balance](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/load-balancing/).

Comment: Makes me think of [Zero-configuration networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking), and [*Bonjour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)) (Apple). I do not know about whether Java implementations exist.

Comment: https://github.com/jmdns/jmdns

Comment: @hfontanez I am trying to make a remote PC application. This will not work on the global internet. Only local network. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by use `DatagramSocket` to UDP broadcast to 192.168.1.255.